# Very large numbers in Java - long addition

Tags: java, try-catch, addition

I'm writing a program for addding large numbers but without using BigInteger. I have a problem in long addition though.

```
int l = this.arr.length > arg.arr.length ? this.arr.length : arg.arr.length;        
byte[] result = new byte[l];    
byte carry = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < result.length; i++){
        byte sum;

        try{
            sum = (byte) (this.arr[i] + arg.arr[i] + carry);
        }
        catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
            try{
                sum = (byte) (this.arr[i] + carry);
            }
            catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ex){
                sum = (byte) (arg.arr[i] + carry);
            }
        }

        //carry
        if(sum > 9){
            result[i] = (byte) (sum % 10);
            carry = 1;
        }
        else{
            result[i] = sum;
            carry = 0;
        }
}

if(carry > 0){
        byte[] tmp = new byte[l+1];
        System.arraycopy(result, 0, tmp, 0, l);
        tmp[tmp.length - 1] = carry;
        result = tmp;
}
```

So to add two numbers I'm using try-catch twice to check whether there are any digits left in either of arrays. The method's working fine but this try-catch thing doesn't look so nice. Could I do this in any other way?

Comment: Please don't use exceptions to do your bounds checking.  I would use an `int[]` with 32-bit values (as does BigInteger) instead of a `byte[0]` with decimal when you get a chance to change it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an `if` statement to check that `i` is `<` `this.arr.length`.

Comment: Ugh, the solution was so simple I can't believe it didn't cross my mind. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a way and you **should** use it instead of a try-catch block. To check for IndexOutOfBounds, simply check if the index is out of bounds, i.e. if it is less than or equal to the array size. Doing a try catch for such checks is definetely not a good idea.

As you have two index operations in the particular try-catch you will have to check the array sizes separately.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you need to rewrite this as follows:

```
    if(i < this.arr.length && i < arg.arr.length)
        sum = (byte) (this.arr[i] + arg.arr[i] + carry);
    else if(i < this.arr.length)
        sum = (byte) (this.arr[i] + carry);
    else
        sum = (byte) (arg.arr[i] + carry);
```

BTW, your method will work incorrectly if you have value in `carry` after loop is over, you need to append this value to result array also.